# Jquery Mixitup plugin help prevent handlers being destroyed

Tags: jquery, tags, jquery-ui-sortable

**UPDATE**: This is the error in the console.

> uncaught exception: query function not defined for Select2 undefined

I am using this code to allow users to add tags to images. Everything works fine. The problem I am running into is when the images are sorted(using mixitup.io plugin). Before sorting, the script works perfect(popup,edit,save,db update). After user clicks a few of the sort buttons, The script stops responding and the popup will not fire.

Please have a look below and help me find where the problem is. Thanks :)

Working code:

```
$('.tags').editable({

    placement: 'top',
    select2: {
        tags: ['cookies', 'pie','cake'],
        tokenSeparators: [","]
    },
    display: function(value) {
        $.each(value,function(i){
           value[i] = "<span class='tagBox'>" + $('<p>' + value[i] + '</p>').text() + "</span>";
        });
        $(this).html(value.join(" "));
    }
});
```

To prevent mixitup.io plugin from destroying the handler, it says to use "delegate()".
I have tried all kinds of different code/combos, but no luck. here is the last attempt

```
$('#content').delegate( ".tags", "click", function() {


$('.tags').editable({

    placement: 'top',
    select2: {
        tags: ['cookies', 'pie','cake'],
        tokenSeparators: [","]
    },
    display: function(value) {
        $.each(value,function(i){
           value[i] = "<span class='tagBox'>" + $('<p>' + value[i] + '</p>').text() + "</span>";
        });
        $(this).html(value.join(" "));
    }
});

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Waht I know is that mixitup sort function destroies the element so all binded events **to those elements** will be lost.

the quick solution is: dont bind events to those elements!

for example you have a link in your items with binded `click` event on them.

```
$("a.clickable").on("click",function(){//....});
```

so as I said just bind the click event to another parent element like `body`:

```
$("body").on("click",'a.clickable' ,function(){//....}); // tested it good solution.
```